# How do I assign the right content to the right div class dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that assigns string values to a div.  I was wondering how can I have it where the content is specific to a specific Div when I call the function?  Obviously I could do the whole [0], [1], [2], etc., but that would defeat the purpose of making this very user friendly.  I realize the For Loop here assigns to all the div with class property.

HTML

```
<div id="property">
   <p>Properties</p>
   <div class="properties" onclick="AddProperty('house# 35C', '3-4', '$50')"></div>
   <div class="properties" onclick="AddProperty('house# 22F', '7-8', '$75')"></div>
   <div class="properties" onclick="AddProperty('house# 19D', '9-10', '$100')"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function AddProperty(propnum, sleepdays, rent) {
   var myProperties =document.getElementsByClassName("properties");
   for (var i=0; i<myProperties.length; i++) {   
      myProperties[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      myProperties[i].innerHTML = new Array(propnum, sleepdays, rent)
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I could just assign Ids and that will work.  I was wondering if there is a way without doing that.  This is sort of a learning thing for me.

Comment: If Ids is the only way to achieve this, let me know folks.  Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the end? Are you just trying to add a unique id for each like 1,2,3,etc. ... or are you trying to get some other unique attribute appended?

Comment: That would be nice. If you could show me how to do that.  Pretty sure what I'm asking only Id assignments is the only thing that will work

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to add an id you would use element.id like this::

```
function AddProperty(propnum, sleepdays, rent) {
   var myProperties =document.getElementsByClassName("properties");
   for (var i=0; i<myProperties.length; i++) {   
      myProperties[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      myProperties[i].innerHTML = new Array(propnum, sleepdays, rent)
      myProperties[i].id = i+1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should use "this":

`<div class="properties" onclick="AddProperty(this, 'house# 35C', '3-4', '$50')">1</div>`

and js will be

`window.AddProperty = function(el, propnum, sleepdays, rent) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    el.innerHTML = new Array(propnum, sleepdays, rent)
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/n7gdbgdu/